# Работа PHP-скрипта в фоне

Tags: php, linux, vds

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть PHP-скрипт, где в бесконечном цикле `<?php while(true) {...}` выполняются команды с консоли, прочитанные с помощью `readline()`. Т.е. при запуске PHP-скрипта, он создает свою консоль, где можно выполнять мои команды, например `get http://google.com` и при нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd> отобразится результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же помимо команд, PHP-скрипт выполняет и другие действия в своем бесконечном цикле, поэтому он должен работать всегда. А чтобы он работал всегда, я использую утилиту *screen*. Создаю окно командой `screen -S name` и запускаю в нем PHP-скрипт. При входе на сервер, чтобы подключиться опять к этом окну использую команду `screen -r name`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое можно реализовать:

При написании команды в Bash `phpscript start` запускать этот PHP-скрипт в фоне. При команде `phpscript stop` вырубать этот скрипт. И при написании команды `phpscript` меня подключало к этому PHP-скрипту (как новое окно *screen*), чтобы я мог отправлять ему команды.

Comment: Раз скрипт у вас уже есть и вы уже умеете пользоваться screen, то не понимаю сути вашего вопроса, все что вам надо вы уже умеете. разве что при старте системы запустить `screen -d -n -S имя php ваш-скрипт.php` ну так это и в доке на screen написано

Comment: @Mike хотелось бы научиться делать такие команды на linux, но даже не понимаю, как это реализовывать. И еще надо бы сделать, чтобы при старте PHP-скрипт запускался сам, как, например, Nginx.

Comment: ну так написанную мной выше строку куда нибудь в загрузку положите. А где именно у вас загрузка зависит от дистрибутива linux. посмотрите /etc/init.d для начала. В gentoo например есть каталог /etc/local.d как раз для таких вещей

Answer (score -1):

С помощью [обработки сигналов](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-signal.php).

А что бы скрипт не прерывался при потере связи с терминалом необходимо выполнить. `ignore_user_abort(true)` и запускать unix-процесс в бэкграунде.